# jQuery true and false

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function abc() {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            $.get("/Game/CheckName", { plName: name }, function (data) {
                alert(data); // here data = true
                    if (data == true) { // i tried so (if (data)) but it didn't work too
                        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("List", "Game")';
                    } else {
                        alert("Name is already use!");
                    }
            });            
        }
```

in this code `(if (data == true))` value always = false. Why? How can i change it?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is contained in `data`? A string or a boolean?

Comment: data might be a string so data == 'true' might be more appropriate

Comment: try using `console.log` to examine the contents of `data`.

Comment: I noticed that you said that you tried just doing if(data)  and that it did not work,  but I believe that is the correct syntax (not if (data == true)  or  if(data == 'true')). Have you tried logging your data (console.log) to make sure you are getting  anything back?

Comment: There are only 5 false values: `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, and `false`. If you tried `if(data)` and it was false, then `data` was one of the above values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give that the following assumption is correct (this this is often the cause of this sort of problem):

> `/Game/CheckName` returns a piece of text that is either the word "true" or the word "false"

Then the solution is:

Compare **strings**, not booleans.

```
if (data === "true") {}
```

Beware whitespace in your output. It will stop the code matching an exact string. You can avoid that possibility by checking for the substring "true" appearing anywhere in the result:

```
if (data.indexOf('true') >= 0) {}
```

Comment: +1 for being explicit in your assumptions.

Comment: +0 for making assumptions.

Comment: error was such : controller return value in hight registr = ("True")

Answer (score 0):

Compare it like string data == 'true'

Answer (score -5):

try

```
if (data === true)
```

instead

Comment: if `data==true` returns `false`, `data===true` will *never* return true.